# Can Chrome Extensions steal OAuth tokens from redirect-uri?

Tags: authentication, oauth2

This is a [duplicate of a stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556339/can-chrome-extensions-steal-oauth-tokens-from-redirect-uri), since it might apply more to security and authentication best practices.

I'm working on auth between a Chrome Extension, Google Cloud Platform, and trying to send the `id_token` JWT to an AWS server to retrieve user data (and/or establish a session?).

My question is this -- how can I prevent chrome extensions with `tabs` permissions from reading the GET request or the redirected URI which has the fully-validated user JWT?

The JWT confirms that a user is who they are, but how do I know my Chrome Extension is the one making the request to my backend?

I have a few ideas:

1. Maybe I can make a private window that only my extension can control
2. Maybe I can somehow use the nonce or get the nonce from my server first
3. Maybe my chrome extension has a private key or some way to verify itself with my backend, which has the public key

Any help would be appreciated, it's difficult to research this specific scenario.

---

```
var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth' +
          '?client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(chrome.runtime.getManifest().oauth2.client_id) +
          '&response_type=id_token' +
          '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()) +
          '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(chrome.runtime.getManifest().oauth2.scopes.join(' ')) +
          '&nonce=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000);

chrome.windows.create({ url: 'about:blank' }, function ({ tabs }) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
        function googleAuthorizationHook(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
            if (tab.id === tabs[0].id) {
                if (tab.title !== 'about:blank') {
                    console.log(url);
                    if (tab.title.startsWith(chrome.identity.getRedirectURL())) {
                        const id_token = tab.title.split('#')[1];
                        console.log(id_token);
                    } else {
                        console.error(tab.title)
                    }

                    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(googleAuthorizationHook);
                    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
                }
            }
        }
    );

    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, { 'url': url });
});
```

Comment: Yes; this has been asked (minus the OAUTH, which really is just cookie + parameters, so nothing "special" from the point of view of the browser) before: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15259/worst-case-scenario-what-can-a-chrome-extension-do-with-your-data-on-all-websi